# Firebird unicode SQL search behaves different on LIKE and = on some characters

Tags: sql, firebird, icu, firebird2.5

Running Firebird Classic v2.5.9 on Gentoo Linux and using system wide ICU library (version 72) I came across strange search results between the = operator and the LIKE operator search regarding certain unicode characters (in my case the polish l).

I simplified the use case to the following example:

```
select 
    case 
        when 'l' collate unicode_ci_ai = 'ł' collate unicode_ci_ai 
            then 'equal' 
            else 'differ' 
    end 
from 
    rdb$database;

-- Result: equal

select 
    case 
        when 'l' collate unicode_ci_ai like 'ł' collate unicode_ci_ai 
            then 'equal' 
            else 'differ' 
    end 
from 
    rdb$database;

-- Result: differ
```

Paradoxically: when I create a unique index on a column with a `unicode_ci_ai` collation and a unique constraint things behave different:

```
CREATE TABLE foo 
(
    COL1  VARCHAR(10) COLLATE UNICODE_CI_AI
);

ALTER TABLE foo ADD CONSTRAINT UNQ1_FOO UNIQUE (COL1);

INSERT INTO foo VALUES ('l');
-- Result: OK

INSERT INTO foo VALUES ('ł');
-- Result: Error
--  violation of PRIMARY or UNIQUE KEY constraint "UNQ1_FOO" on table "FOO".
--  Problematic key value is ("COL1" = 'l').
```

With other 'non-standard' characters (é for example) the both search strategies give the same result:

```
select case when 'e' collate unicode_ci_ai = 'é' collate unicode_ci_ai then 'equal' else 'differ' end from rdb$database;
-- Result: equal

select case when 'e' collate unicode_ci_ai like 'é' collate unicode_ci_ai then 'equal' else 'differ' end from rdb$database;
-- Result: equal
```

Is it a bug or a feature? It the latter - then why?

Comment: Have you tried this in a supported version, like Firebird 3.0.10 or Firebird 4.0.2? If it works there, then it is likely a bug.

Comment: I tested the issue with Firebird 3.0.7 on Windows (ICU version 52 included) - the issue is still there. With Firebird 4.0.1 also on Windows (ICU version 63 included) I can't reproduce it any more.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be tackled by the Firebird team:

https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/firebird/issues/5044

and already fixed in 4.0 Beta 2.